# Is there a photo service that allows to upload preserving folder structure

Tags: software, file-management, software-recommendation, photo-management, service-recommendation

This might be not strictly a photography question. But I imagine that someone had this problem before. I have quite large collection of digital photos organized in folders. Some of those are uploaded to Google Photos, some to Flickr (free version), but it gets tiresome to keep things up to date.

My question is - is there a service that allows to upload your photo collection and easily create albums / galleries / ... based on your folder structure? Preferably with a dedicated Windows uploader application.

I'm considering 500px or Flickr subscription, but from what I see 500px does not have an uploader and Flickr does not have an option to create albums from folders.

Comment: No idea but have your tried uploading a folder? I would expect any cloud storage to keep the folder structure, otherwise it would have to manage conflicts and would simply be a pain.

Comment: Google Drive does keep the folder structure but does not allow to create a Google Photos album from uploaded Google Drive folder. It looks like Lightroom with Flickr / 500px plugin might be an option, but it would be great if someone using similar workflow could confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com) (formerly SkyDrive) is a cloud service that should suit your needs.

If you are a Windows user, you can have it integrated to the Windows Explorer and use this program as an uploader. Drag&drop to a web browser window is another option.

It does support the directory structure. (I'm not sure about the maximum depth though.)

[image: Microsoft OneDrive]

Comment: Does it allow direct links to the pcture? I mean if I uploaded a photo into "_rootfolder/2017/august/pic1.jpg_" will I be able to link it as something like "_onedrive.live.com/my_account_code/2017/august/pic1.jpg_"? Dropbox allowed this but not any more.

Comment: From my brief testing it does allow to link not only to individual files but also to create albums from folders. Still not automated but better than in Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Flickr has an API which allows people to write their own uploaders, and which supports [creating photosets](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.create.html) (which I think is an alias for albums). There are at least some tools around which use it: see e.g. https://github.com/trickortweak/flickr-uploader ; https://github.com/rdvdijk/flickr_uploader

If you want to use Flickr but can't find a tool which does exactly what you want, you could hire someone to produce it. Creating a basic uploader is probably on the order of two to six hours for someone who's familiar with REST APIs. If you don't have any friends or contacts who freelance, there are websites for hiring freelance programmers.

Comment: Those tools look really interesting, might do just what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve written a simple free and open source multi-platform desktop app that does exactly that:  http://jiotty-photos-uploader.yudichev.net/. It’s been used quite a lot by now and is considered stable.

Jiotty Photos Uploader is a simple desktop application for Windows, macOS and Linux that scans a folder, including all subfolders, for photos and videos, and uploads them to your Google Photos gallery arranging into albums according to the directory structure.